# Soma de Dias Uteis

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Existe alguma forma de somar dias uteis a uma data, que não utilize laços de repetição (Como while e for)?

Atualmente utilizo esse código

```
var novaData = new Date(dataBase.valueOf());
var diasUteisRemanescente;
var isFimDeSemana;
var direcao;


// Remove decimais 
if (diasSoma !== parseInt(diasSoma, 10)) { throw new TypeError('AdicionaDiaUtil utiliza apenas dias uteis.'); }

// Se zero dias, não realiza mudança 
if (diasSoma === 0) { return dataBase; }

//Decide soma ou subtração 
direcao = diasSoma > 0 ? 1 : -1;

//decide numero de iterações
diasUteisRemanescente = Math.abs(diasSoma);

//Intera até chegar zerar os dias 
while (diasUteisRemanescente) {
    // adiciona/subtrai um dia 
    novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + direcao);
    //Verifica se o dia é util
    if (isSabadoUtil) {
        isFimDeSemana = novaData.getDay() in { 0: 'Sunday' };
    }
    else {
        isFimDeSemana = novaData.getDay() in { 0: 'Sunday', 6: 'Saturday' };
    }
    //Se for util remove um dia 
    if (!isFimDeSemana) { diasUteisRemanescente--; }
}
return novaData;
```

Comment: Com ou sem "gambiarra"?

Comment: Pode haver ou não

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer o pretendido, substituindo o ciclo *while* por uma chamada recursiva a uma determinada função:

```
var novaData = new Date(dataBase.valueOf());
var diasUteisRemanescente;
var direcao;

// Remove decimais 
if (diasSoma !== parseInt(diasSoma, 10)) {
    throw new TypeError('AdicionaDiaUtil utiliza apenas dias uteis.');
}

// Se zero dias, não realiza mudança 
if (diasSoma === 0) { return dataBase; }

//Decide soma ou subtração 
direcao = diasSoma > 0 ? 1 : -1;

//decide numero de iterações
diasUteisRemanescente = Math.abs(diasSoma);

// Chamada recursiva
novaData = >>>> calculaNovaData(novaData, diasUteisRemanescente, direcao); <<<<

return novaData;
```

E a nova função seria algo do género:

```
function calculaNovaData(data, dias, direcao) {
    if (dias == 0) {
        return data;
    }

    var isFimDeSemana;

    // adiciona/subtrai um dia 
    data.setDate(data.getDate() + direcao);
    //Verifica se o dia é util
    if (isSabadoUtil) {
        isFimDeSemana = data.getDay() in { 0: 'Sunday' };
    }
    else {
        isFimDeSemana = data.getDay() in { 0: 'Sunday', 6: 'Saturday' };
    }
    //Se for util remove um dia 
    if (!isFimDeSemana) { dias--; }

    return calculaNovaData(data, dias, direcao);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso não queira usar recursividade, pode-se usar o Moments.js 
Utilizando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
moment().businessAdd(7);
moment().businessDiff(moment().subtract(7, 'd'));
```

Comment: fba_pereira, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Agradecemos que queira ajudar! No entanto, a sua resposta se resume a um link que neste momento é válido mas nada nos garante que continue a sê-lo no futuro. O stackoverflow deve ser encarado como um repositório de conhecimento e não apenas um *site* de pergunta e resposta. Ao responder devemos pensar, não só em quem perguntou, mas também em todos aqueles que no futuro poderão usufruir da nossa resposta.